# C program: how to get parent directory's inode number?

Tags: linux, inode

How to get directory inode number say /home/laks/file.txt 
I need the inode number of laks directory. Any built-in function is already available?
I think i could use stat() if i cut the file name...but any other solution to this without removing file name.

Comment: yes this one works
----
#include <libgen.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
main(){
struct stat statbuf;
char *ff="/home/laks/file.txt";
if (stat(dirname(strdup(ff)), &statbuf) != -1)
printf("\n %ld",statbuf.st_ino);
}
-----
thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
...
struct stat statbuf;
if (stat(dirname(argv[1]), &statbuf) != -1)
    process_inode_number(statbuf.st_ino);
```

Note that `dirname()` may modify the string, so if you still need it, or if it may be a string literal (which is in read-only memory), then use `strdup()` to make a copy of the string for `dirname()`.

Comment: thanks I tried to run this way 
#include <libgen.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
main(){
struct stat statbuf;
if (stat(dirname("/home/laks/file.txt"), &statbuf) != -1)
 printf("\n %lld",statbuf.st_ino);
}

But it core dumps -- any thoughts

Comment: If you are using a string literal then use strdup.  i.e. `strdup("/home/laks/file.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

```
a=/home/laks/file.txt
dir=${a%/*}
set -- $(ls -ldi $dir)
echo $1
```

or if you want to recurse directory

```
find /path -type f -name "*.txt" -printf 'stat -c "%%n:%%i" "%h"\n' | sort -u |bash
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible to do the same using C API ?

Comment: sorry, missed out the programming language. Hope somebody can answer you soon.

Comment: Not your fault. I edited title only after your replied. So it's my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

try : `ls -ali`  on shell. You can find `inode` numbers on 3rd column.